# i open link from custom fields but it open along with original site

Tags: php, wordpress

i make custom field in wordpress and insert link there like www.google.com i get this custom field like this

```
<?php $episode=get_post_meta($post->ID, "download_link", true);

                    ?>


                <a class="more-linkk" href="<?php echo $episode ;?>" target="_blank"></a>
```

now it opens in url like this http://dramapk.net/movie/www.google.com i want it just open google.com so kindly guide me

Answer (score 0):

`<a class="more-linkk" href="<?php echo "http://".$episode ;?>" target="_blank"></a>`

If your link doesn't start with the protocol (`http://` or `https://`) the browser puts the domain name before, so your link is invalid.

Comment: thanks so much,its solve, one thing more link opens in new tab i want link open in same tab, any suggestion

Comment: Remove `target="_blank"` to get links opened on the same window/tab.